# ESLint complains for removed package

Tags: node.js, eslint, package.json

I used a boilerplate and removed what I don't needed in it to quick start a little dev environment, but I get an error from ESLint that I don't understand where it's coming from!

Here's my error:

> [Error - 9:28:40 a.m.] Failed to load plugin react-hooks: Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-react-hooks' Referenced from: C:...\wo\package.json

But there's no esling-plugin-react-hooks... where does that come from... ‍♂️

```
{
"name": "web-objects",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"author": "Jonathan Lafleur",
"license": "MIT",
"main": "gulpfile.js",
"dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^9.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "babelify": "^10.0.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.7",
    "del": "^2.0.2",
    "eslint": "^5.14.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint-config-wesbos": "0.0.19",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^5.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^7.0.0",
    "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-csso": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-htmlmin": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^6.1.0",
    "gulp-notify": "^3.2.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.2.1",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.4.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.5",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.8",
    "imagemin-mozjpeg": "^8.0.0",
    "install-peerdeps": "^1.10.2",
    "prettier": "^1.16.4",
    "run-sequence": "^2.2.1"
},
"eslintConfig": {
    "env": {
        "es6": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "wesbos"
    ]
},
"browserslist": [
    "last 5 version",
    "> 2%",
    "IE 10"
],
"scripts": {
    "start": "gulp dev",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "lint:fix": "eslint . --fix",
    "build": "gulp build",
    "sync": "npm run build && aws s3 sync ./dist/ s3://sia-webobjects --delete"
}
}
```

Comment: If you use VSCode the problem is probably caused by a deprecated setting for prettier. See [here](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/910#issuecomment-526869578)

Comment: You use `eslint-config-wesbos` which requires `eslint-plugin-react-hooks`.

Comment: Damn ! That's wesbos config ... Guess i'll have to extend my own then. Thank you